# Can anyone help me with google extension icons?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a problem with Google Extension icons. Namely, only one 32x32 icon appears when I upload my extension as an unpacked extension on chrome://extensions/.

Can anyone send me the correct structure of manifact.json which includes appearing all icons?

Comment: Can you show us what you already coded as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1):

This is the architecture that I use in version 2 of the Manifest, if you are using version 3 you can check the documentation in the following link.

[image]

Manifest v3

```
 {
  // Required
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "My Extension",
  "version": "versionString",

  // Recommended
  "action": {...},
  "default_locale": "en",
  "description": "A plain text description",
  "icons": {...},

  // Optional
  "action": ...,
  "author": ...,
  "automation": ...,
  "background": {
    // Required
    "service_worker":
  },
  "chrome_settings_overrides": {...},
  "chrome_url_overrides": {...},
  "commands": {...},
  "content_capabilities": ...,
  "content_scripts": [{...}],
  "content_security_policy": "policyString",
  "converted_from_user_script": ...,
  "current_locale": ...,
  "declarative_net_request": ...,
  "devtools_page": "devtools.html",
  "differential_fingerprint": ...,
  "event_rules": [{...}],
  "externally_connectable": {
    "matches": ["*://*.example.com/*"]
  },
  "file_browser_handlers": [...],
  "file_system_provider_capabilities": {
    "configurable": true,
    "multiple_mounts": true,
    "source": "network"
  },
  "homepage_url": "http://path/to/homepage",
  "host_permissions": [...],
  "import": [{"id": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"}],
  "incognito": "spanning, split, or not_allowed",
  "input_components": ...,
  "key": "publicKey",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "versionString",
  "nacl_modules": [...],
  "natively_connectable": ...,
  "oauth2": ...,
  "offline_enabled": true,
  "omnibox": {
    "keyword": "aString"
  },
  "optional_permissions": ["tabs"],
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "options_ui": {
    "chrome_style": true,
    "page": "options.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["tabs"],
  "platforms": ...,
  "replacement_web_app": ...,
  "requirements": {...},
  "sandbox": [...],
  "short_name": "Short Name",
  "storage": {
    "managed_schema": "schema.json"
  },
  "system_indicator": ...,
  "tts_engine": {...},
  "update_url": "http://path/to/updateInfo.xml",
  "version_name": "aString",
  "web_accessible_resources": [...]
}
```

Reference : https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/

Comment: Thank you for the right answer to my question you really help me. I have one more question. What is your opinion does it better v2 or v3 manifest?

Comment: It is better to use version 3 since it is possible that Google at some point begins to deprecate version 2, if you do not want to worry about this in the future it is better to use v3

Comment: Okay, thanks. But brother I do everything right and I have a problem again. After 3 hours of countless attempts and wasting time searching, I can't fix the problem with icons. Can you give me your skype or any contact to send you more detail?

Comment: Send me a message here https://www.linkedin.com/in/frank-jos%C3%A9-popo-morera-655b4a13b/